# UITextfield shouldChangeCharactersInRange is not calling when i rotate the view from Portrait to Landscape or vice versa in iPad in iOS7

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uitextfield, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a view in which 2 textfields are there when i rotate the view from Portrait to Landscape or from Landscape to Portrait & tried to enter value through keyboard then nothing will happen. & in most of the cases it crashes.

It works fine till iOS 6 but in iOS 7 its not working.

Please suggest/help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the Delegate set? Posting the code might help.

Comment: @ilight I drag two textfield in view(storyboard). delegate was also connected. first time app is loaded then its works fine but when i rotate the view then in textfield nothing will enter.

Comment: @ilight i got this "UITextField -webView called. This method is no longer supported with the new text architecture" as nslog

Comment: This might help to change your existing code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073960/uitextfield-webview-no-longer-supported

Comment: @ilight not getting right one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After lots of searching & hit and trail I conclude the issue is related to the command key being "stuck" in the simulator if you rotate the device in the simulator using Command-LeftArrow and Command-RightArrow short cuts, one way around this is to rotate the device by selecting the menu option instead of the keyboard shortcut(command+arrow key). This rotates the device, and seems to leave the keyboard in a working state.

so it's a bug in the simulator(iOS7).

Comment: I've been dealing with this exact same issue for weeks I was thinking it was the 3rd party library I've been using. Upvoting.

Comment: I agree with @Holyprin for the exact same reason heh