# UITextField -webView (iOS 7.1)

Tags: ios7, uitextfield

I am getting this console output all of a sudden. What does it mean?

```
UITextField -webView called. This method is no longer supported with the new text architecture
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextFields use to have an underlying UIWebView to show formatted text. With iOS 7, formatted text is drawn using TextKit framework.

In other words, it's depreciated.

[UITextField -webView no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073960/uitextfield-webview-no-longer-supported)